# how to shread and query xml column where the nodes are dynamic in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

We have an xml column where the node names change from site to site (Basically, we allow the users to create custom fields in addition to the standard fields we provide, and these fields are kept in the xml column I mentioned. A sample cell looks like

```
<Dictionary><UnitNumber>56</UnitNumber><AptNo>12</AptNo></Dictionary>
```

Note that the nodes UnitNumber and AptNo are totally customer specific, it could be AutoBrand and ManifestNo and TravelSite.

Now, we allow the customers to query on these fields. The stored proc gets an xml parameter and we parse that xml parameter into a temp table, the table looks like this

```
field         value
-----          -----
UnitNumber      56
AptNo           12
```

So this table is what the customer passed in as where clause (which should be translated to select * from t where UnitNumber = 56 and AptNo = 12)

Then we shred the xml column from the table where the results are going to come from. Since we use the nodes() function and OUTER APPLY, the final CTE has some identities duplicated, since they had more than one node.

The sql statement where we do xml shredding is something as follows

```
SELECT T.C.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomFieldName,
T.C.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as CustomFieldValue,
#tempTable.*
FROM #tempTable
OUTER APPLY #tempTable.CustomFields.nodes('/Dictionary/child::*') as T(C)
```

This returns something like

```
CustomFieldName        CustomFieldValue       EntityId
---------------        ----------------       ----------
UnitNumber               56                     1
AptNo                    12                     1
UnitNumber               56                     2
```

So when we join CTE with the temp table, we join on

```
CustomFieldName = field and CustomFieldValue = value
```

And the query returns both entityId 1 and entityId 2, but I want it to return only entityId 1, because that is the only entity which satisfies both conditions

```
(UnitNumber = 56 AND AptNo = 12)
```

I haven't figured out a way to accomplish this. Of course it would be very helpful if the way we store CustomFields was structured, but this is an established system and can not change it right now.

Any tips are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Great question.  Thanks for posting, I look forward to reading the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could get you closer. Off the top of my head:

```
Select top 1 EntityId from #cte 
left join #tempTable 
on CustomFieldName = field 
and CustomFieldValue = value 
group by EntityId 
order by count(entityid) desc
```

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to use stackoverflow's conventions, but wanted to thank you for your answer. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It did get me close. Following is what I ended up doing

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY EntityId DESC) As EntityCount, EntityId
from CTE JOIN #tempTable ON 
CustomFieldName = field and CustomFieldValue = value 
Where EntityCount = (select count(*) from #temptable)
```

Thank you for your help.